# Django's test client with multiple values for data keys

Tags: django

Django's [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#module-django.test.client) lets you perform `POST` requests and specify request data as a `dict`.

However if I want to send data that mimics `<select multiple>` or `<input type="checkbox">` fields, I need to send multiple values for a single key in the data `dict`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 21):

The simplest way is to specify the values as a `list` or `tuple` in the `dict`:

```
client.post('/foo', data={"key": ["value1", "value2"]})
```

Alternatively you can use a `MultiValueDict` as the value.

Comment: What Django Form field should be use to clean/validate a `list` or `tuple` of values that you are sending via client.post?

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this issue! Unfortunately, your answer did not work for me, In the `FormView` I was posting to it would only pull out one of the values included, not all of the values

You should also be able to build a querystring manually and post it using content type `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
some_str = 'key=value1&key=value2&test=test&key=value3'
client.post('/foo/', some_str, content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict
from django.utils.http import urlencode

form_data = {'username': 'user name',
             'address':  'street',
             'allowed_hosts': ["host1", "host2"]
             }

response = client.post(reverse('new_user'),
                       urlencode(MultiValueDict(form_data), doseq=True),
                       content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

Comment: Most complicated and cleaner solution, Thx